Notification with an action text shows center aligned on Samsung Devices
notification with an action text with a pending intent is always center aligned only on Samsung devices , But on other devices It is left aligned with other texts. I have used  NotificationCompat.Builder().addAction()  method.
Now I want the Samsung device to show notification like others, how to do it?
My expectation is the action type text on notification will show on the left aligned with above text.
Reference Image

The decision of how to render a Notification is mostly up to the device manufacturer, not you or me. If Samsung wants to center-align the action, that is Samsung's decision to make.
